# iMessage App Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, ios10, imessage

Hy Guys, I try to build an iMessage App. I would like to Video send. This video coming from Http Server....

```
import UIKit
import Messages

class MessagesViewController: MSMessagesAppViewController {

 @IBAction func bt3(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //VIDEO URL
        let videoUrl = URL(string: "https://---/app/test/test.m4v")

        let message = MSMessage()
        message.shouldExpire = false

        let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
        layout.mediaFileURL = videoUrl

        message.layout = layout

        let conversation = activeConversation
        conversation?.insert(message, completionHandler: nil)
  }
}
```

what do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

[mediaFileURL Documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/msmessagetemplatelayout/1648043-mediafileurl)

> The media file URL must be a file URL. For video files, the system crops the left and right edges of the media file by 6 points, and rounds its corners. For audio files, it shows a graphical representation of the audio’s waveform.

You can only use mediaFileURL to send local video files. I'd try using the `insertText(_:completionHandler:)` method in the active [MSConversation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/msconversation) to send an inline preview of the view.